# Fatal error in Solr 3.4.0 while indexing MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, tomcat, solr

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to index data from MySQL.

What I need to do?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''400' Status: Bad Request' in C:\Projects\Libraries\Apache\Solr\Service.php:364 Stack trace: #0 C:\Projects\Libraries\Apache\Solr\Service.php(669): Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawPost('http://localhos...', '<add allowDups=...') #1 C:\Projects\Libraries\Apache\Solr\Service.php(697): Apache_Solr_Service->add('<add allowDups=...') #2 C:\Projects\dasaran\public\index.php(27): Apache_Solr_Service->addDocument(Object(Apache_Solr_Document)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\Projects\Libraries\Apache\Solr\Service.php on line 364
```

Comment: And the relevance to PHP?

Comment: How do you index? Are you doing it with a Data Import Handler (DIH)? If so, how is its config? If not, have you rolled your own indexer? If so, how is its code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I had a unique field id, but I didn't input a value to that field.

Just a suggestion to all beginners as I am, read error logs.